# Script to `grep` a file with variable

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

```
while read wholeline
do
  echo ${wholeline} --outputs John Jones
  #grab all the lines that begin with these values
  #grep '^John Jones' workfile2   --works, prints contents of workfile2 where the 1st matches
  grep '^${wholeline}' workfile2  # --does not work. why? it should be the same result.
done < workfile1
```

`workfile1` contains the value `John Jones` at the beginning of the line in the file.

`workfile2` contains the value `John Jones` at the beginning of the line in the file.

How can I change that second `grep` statement so that it works?
It is picking up nothing.

Comment: **Don't** post images of code, and don't overwrite someone else's edit unless you are improving on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes, try using double quotes. For the shell to expand variables, you need to use double quotes.

```
while read wholeline
do
  echo ${wholeline} --outputs John Jones
  #grab all the lines that begin with these values
  #grep '^John Jones' workfile2   # --works, prints contents of workfile2
                                  # where the 1st matches
  grep "^${wholeline}" workfile2  # --does work now, since shell 
                                  # expands ${wholeline} in double quotes
done < workfile1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I needed double quotes indeed. Great site. I will learn how to format my questions properly for next time.

Comment: +1, but please do read the markdown help to properly format your answers